# Python Script to Convert SVG to OBJ Not Working

Tags: python, scripting

My intention is to run Blender headless on a server and automatically import an SVG object, convert it to OBJ, and export it. I can run my create_function line by line within Blender and it works perfectly. When I try to run it as a python script externally it fails. It says RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.convert.poll() failed, context is incorrect.

I got this type of error before when developing the script in Blender, but I made corrections and don't get it anymore. My script is a near duplicate of the background_job.py sample from Blender with this function added. I was printing my import and export path variables and they appear fine. My SVG is a single object that comes in as a closed curve.

Any idea why this is happening? I have no experience in Python, so please keep that in mind when helping.

```
def create_function(import_path, export_path):
    # Clear existing objects.
    bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)
    print("import path ",import_path," export path ",export_path)
    if import_path:
        bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath=import_path)

    pattern = bpy.context.scene.objects["pOutline"]
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = pattern
    pattern.select_set(True)
    bpy.data.curves["pOutline"].dimensions = "2D"
    bpy.data.curves["pOutline"].fill_mode = "BOTH"
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target="MESH")
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="SELECT")
    bpy.ops.uv.unwrap()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    if export_path:
        bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=export_path, use_selection=True,
                                 use_materials=False)
```